# Using a weapon made for a creature smaller than yourself, but of your size?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, creature-size

Because of the rules regarding category sizes it is not very handy to use something like a medium-sized longsword as a creature of size category Large or Huge (because of the -2 or -4 modifyer on hitting someone). The Arms and Equipment Guide has a possible solution: the Fullblade. A Huge-sized exotic weapon that a Medium creature needs a feat to be able to wield, it should be a perfect fit for a Huge creature... I think. It makes mention in the text that a Large-sized creature can use it with two hands like a regular two-handed weapon, but I am not sure if this invokes negative modifyers. So I wonder the following:

**How does wielding a Huge weapon designed for a Medium creature affect a Huge creature? How about a smaller creature? Or is a better alternative than the Fullblade?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weapons underwent a massive design change between D&D 3e (A&EG) and D&D 3.5e: the former has weapons divided by size (a longsword is a medium weapon, which means a huge giant uses it as if it were a dagger), while the latter has weapon sizes (a longsword is a one-handed weapon, a dagger is a light one and you can have normal longswords and huge daggers and while they do the same damage they are different).
Hence, there are no huge weapons designed for medium creatures in D&D 3.5e.
Instead of delving in the rules for wielding a weapon made for a creature of different size (a huge giant can not hold a medium longsword, as I discovered in the worst moment, but can hold a two-handed medium weapon as if it was a light weapon with a -4 penalty to hit) I'd just head to the better (but costly) alternative.

You can use the *Sizing* weapon enchantment (*Magic Item Compendium*, p. 43) to have a weapon that changes to your size when you morph with a swift action. Since you're not wearing but wielding it, I think it doesn't get subsumed in your new form.

Comment: Sizing doesn't automatically change the weapon size. It lets you change it as a Swift action.

Comment: Wildling Clasps only work on neck items and vests, so not on weapons. So you'll have to either drop it (not desirable: it costs a minor action to pick up, you can't do it all the time and it is easily saboutaged by a mean DM.) or use storage space inside of a vest-based magic item.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs that was the 3e version of it. 3.5e works on any item worn on the body. (However, you're righ, not on wielded ones